# Side by side divs with no gap?

Tags: html, alignment, css

I am referring to this Fiddle I found on SO that uses `display: inline-block;` and I have applied it to my own work but I can't figure out how to get the two divs to sit flush side by side, not with the 3-4px gap?

http://jsfiddle.net/zygnz/1/

I've tried:

html

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="left">
            LEFT
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            RIGHT
        </div>
</div>
```

css

```
div.left {
    background:blue;
    height:200px;
    width:300px;
}

div.right{
    background:green;
    height:300px;
    width:100px;
}

.container{
    background:black;
    height:400px;
    width:450px;
}

.container div {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

But got nothing.

Comment: `display: inline-block` add some gap between the applied elements. to remove that gap, don't give space between the elements in HTML code like this: `<span></span><div></div>` or use `float: left` instead of `display: inline-block`. if you want to still go with `display: inline-block` then there is a fix for it to apply margin in negative values in the unit of `em`. I think that is `-0.36em`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `float:left` but also try setting margins on div.left and div.right to 0 like:

```
margin:0 auto;
```

So, with your fiddle:

```
div.left {
    background:blue;
    height:200px;
    width:300px;
    margin:0 auto;
    float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually you dont have to change anything in css to avoid the gap,

> this is a whitespace problem in HTML,

change the html to this

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="left">LEFT
        </div><div class="right">RIGHT
        </div>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/zygnz/2259/)

OR

you can edit your css

You can use `float:left;` instead of `display:inline-block;` to nullify the whitespace problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you set display: inline-block; then add `margin-right: -4px;` to remove the gap.

[see this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zygnz/2257/)

Comment: Brilliant, that works but is that the nicest way of doing it though?

Comment: alternatively you can use float: left;

Comment: you can remove the new line between the elements in the HTML

Answer (score 1):

Use 2 span's (now divs), make the inline-block and don't leave any spaces or new lines between them. Use spans not divs because some old ies can't make inline-block elements from default block elements like divs.

**Like this:**

```
<span style="display: inline-block">one</span><span style="display: inline-block">two</span>
```

**Not like this:**

```
<span style="display: inline-block">one</span> <span style="display: inline-block">two</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather using `display:inline-block` you can `float` the `div's` ,just change the `css` to

```
.container div {
float:left;
}
```

The above code should get the required result.It will align the `div` right next to each other without any space.

Refer the links below to see what caused the white space or about `float` and `display:inline block`

[Reference 1](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)

[Reference 2](http://www.ternstyle.us/blog/float-vs-inline-block)